# How can BottomSheetBehavior, AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior, and AppBarLayout.Behavior work together in unison?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, bottom-sheet

In the GIF below you'll see I'm having trouble coordinating (heh) an [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html), containing a [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html), and a [Persistent BottomSheet](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets) in such a way that they play nicely together

---

[image]

---

**Goal:** *Have the [fragment contents](https://github.com/forrestbice/AdvancedCoordinatorLayoutBehaviorStackOverflowQuestionSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L43), seen above in turquoise ([#26999f](https://github.com/forrestbice/AdvancedCoordinatorLayoutBehaviorStackOverflowQuestionSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml#L13)), remain above, yet scroll behind, the BottomSheet, seen above in dark green [(#12783e)](https://github.com/forrestbice/AdvancedCoordinatorLayoutBehaviorStackOverflowQuestionSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L53), while also respecting the AppBarLayout and its Behavior*

Again, as you can see from the GIF I'm close; the fragment contents is using a [custom layout_behavior](https://github.com/forrestbice/AdvancedCoordinatorLayoutBehaviorStackOverflowQuestionSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L47), [MyScrollingViewBehavior](https://github.com/forrestbice/AdvancedCoordinatorLayoutBehaviorStackOverflowQuestionSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/forrestbice/advancedcoordinatorlayoutbehaviorstackoverflowquestionsample/MyScrollingViewBehavior.java), which extends [AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html)

In the code snippet below you'll see `MyScrollingViewBehavior#layoutDependsOn` returns `true` if the `dependency` is an instance of either a `RelativeLayout` (The BottomSheet in this example) or whatever `super` (`AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior#layoutDependsOn`) is depentent on

```
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof RelativeLayout ||
            super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency);
}
```

Within `MyScrollingViewBehavior#onDependentViewChanged` if the `dependency` is an instance of a `RelativeLayout`, meaning the dependency is the BottomSheet, the child, aka fragment contents, is moved up or down using `offsetTopAndBottom` to ensure it remains above the BottomSheet

```
@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
    if (dependency instanceof RelativeLayout) {
        RelativeLayout bottomSheet = (RelativeLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        int bottomSheetHeight = (bottomSheet.getTop() - child.getBottom());
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(child, bottomSheetHeight);
    }
    super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
    return false;
}
```

The full code sample can be found [on Github here](https://github.com/forrestbice/AdvancedCoordinatorLayoutBehaviorStackOverflowQuestionSample). Additionally, this question is a followup and hopeful improvement to [my original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518504/persistent-bottomsheet-below-fragment-contents)

Comment: Not clear the goal, what means "while also respecting the AppBarLayout and its Behavior"

Comment: @GPack by that I mean the fragment contents will still scroll beneath the collapsable toolbar and will expand it when the user has reached the top of the fragment and attempts to scroll up more. However this behavior isn't unique to my problem and that's why left those details out but I hope this clarifies things. If not I'm happy to provide more of an explanation!

Comment: sorry, I dont understand what is the trouble: all works nice in my opinion.

Comment: At the end of the GIF you'll see the BottomSheet completely cover the toolbar, that's the biggest problem