# BottomSheet below fragment: how to make bottom sheet not overlap the fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack, material-components-android, bottom-sheet

I'm working on a music player with the player controls and track details inside a bottom sheet. When the bottom sheet is closed, only the player controls are shown, when it's opened, it shows the track details. Something relatively standard.

[image]
[image]

My problem is I can't find the way to position the bottom of the fragment above the bottom sheet — the one containing the artits, album, etc. — to the top of the bottom sheet. The bottom sheet always end up overlapping the bottom of the fragment above.

[image]

Unhopefully, it's not as simple as setting a bottom margin to the fragment because the bottom sheet can be hidden when nothing is playing.

So far, the closest thread I found with someone appearing to have the same problem is [this one, with no response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518504/persistent-bottomsheet-below-fragment-contents). Frankly, I'm quite surprised no-one seemed to have the same use-case before.